# Keep UITabBarController Visible in View Hierarchy (Storyboard)

Tags: ios, ios5, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller

I know that traditionally, if I was creating my own `UITabBarController`, I could push a new `ViewController` on to the stack with each tab and keep the bar visible at the bottom of the screen. I am, however, using my first storyboard project.

Storyboard doesn't let me set the initial view of each tab as a `UINavigationController`. What are my options here?

Comment: http://maybelost.com/2011/10/tutorial-storyboard-in-xcode-4-2-with-navigation-controller-and-tabbar-controller-part1/

Answer (score 0):

To keep the Tab Bar at the bottom of a new view, you just need to embed the first ViewController in a NavigationController and then use Push segues to transition to any additional ViewControllers that you add on after that.

**If using a TabBarApplication Template:**

1. Select the FirstViewController.
2. Go to the Editor Tab and select "Embed In" dropdown.
3. Select "Navigation Controller.
4. Create a Push segue from the FirstViewController to any new Viewcontroller that you add after that.

**If Using a SingleViewApplication Template:**

1. Create a UIViewController
2. Select the Viewcontroller and embed that into a NavigationContoller as described above.
3. Select the new NavigationController, go to Editor and click "Embed In" and then select TabBarController
4. Create another ViewController for the other tab, embed that into a NavigationController and Control-Click-Drag from the TabBarController to the NavigationController and select "View Controller" in the "relationship segue" section.

To my knowledge, this can only be done when using Push segues. As soon as you add a Modal view, the Tab Bar will disappear. You can, however make your navigation bar hidden when using the push segue, if you don't want there to be one. then to close it, just have some button (or function) dismiss it like so:

`[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

Or you could use an unwind Segue, if you are using iOS 6.

Hope this answered your question. If unclear, just let me know.

For help on Storyboards [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1)
 was great for me.